# Best way to handle a form with password field in CakePHP 1.3?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.3, cakephp-model

I have a User controller and User model. This model and associated database table is used for authentication and naturally there's a password field.

In my `edit` action when I call `$this->data` is puts the hashed password in my password field in my `edit` view. Naturally, I don't want a password field with a 40-character value, which will then get re-hashed upon save.

My action looks like this:

```
function edit($id) {
    $this->User->id = $id;
    if (empty($this->data)) {
        $this->data = $this->User->read();
    }
    else {
        if ($this->User->save($this->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash('User has been updated.');
            $this->redirect(array('action' => 'view', $this->User->id));
        }
    }
}
```

And my view looks like this:

```
<h2>Edit User</h2>
<?php
    echo $this->Form->create('User', array('action' => 'edit'));
    echo $this->Form->input('username');
    echo $this->Form->input('password');
    echo $this->Form->input('first_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('last_name');
    echo $this->Form->input('email');
    echo $this->Form->end('Save User');
?>
```

How can I have a form for users to edit their account (username etc) that doesn't update the password if left blank, but does update it if the user enters a new password into the password field?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common & most secure method is to have a separate form for changing the password where you ask the user to confirm the change by asking the old password. This is because if you forget the site open on a public computer, the next person who comes in can't just hijack the account by just giving a new password.

If you still want to go with the original plan, you can unset the variable if it's empty before saving the data:

```
if( $this->data[ 'User' ][ 'password' ] == '' ) {
    unset( $this->data[ 'User' ][ 'password' ] );
}
```

The other option is to list allowed fields as a parameter to `save()` and leave out `password` if the field is empty.

In the view you can use

```
echo $this->Form->input('password', array( 'value' => '' ) );
```

to keep the hash from showing up in the field.

Comment: Of course! Thanks. I'll go down the separate form for changing the password.

Comment: Generally the user edit form would not handle passwords, and the action associated with the edit would not even allow the password field via the fields key in the save call. As long as the validation on the password field is NOT set to "required" => true (meaning, must be in the data array to save a user) and the field is simply missing from the general edit form you will be fine.

Comment: use a behavior for a clean approach: https://github.com/dereuromark/tools/blob/master/models/behaviors/change_password.php

Answer (score 0):

Most places only allow editing passwords when they enter their original passwords. It helps protect against password changes with unauthorized access.

But if you want to do it, try

```
echo $this->Form->input('password', array('default'=>false));
```

Comment: Doing only this will blank the password in the database when the field is left empty.